# How to create check constraint in mysql diagram view?

Tags: mysql, diagram, check-constraints

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
newbook_mast (book_id varchar(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE,          
book_name varchar(50)  ,           
isbn_no varchar(15)  NOT NULL UNIQUE  ,           
cate_id varchar(8)  ,             
aut_id varchar(8) ,             
pub_id varchar(8) ,            
dt_of_pub date ,             
pub_lang varchar(15) ,           
no_page decimal(5,0)            
book_price decimal(8,2) ,             
PRIMARY KEY (book_id)               
);
```

If I wanted to add a check on a column I would simply write :

```
CHECK(no_page>0)
```

But instead of writing the code I am creating diagram models in the mysql workbench. 
I am unable to find how I can add a check like above by just using the diagram model?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL Workbench as of at least version 8.0.19 does not support CHECK constraints in navigator, table editor, or diagrams.

This has been reported as a missing feature:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95143 *No support for CHECK constraints in Workbench*

You should log into the bugs site and click the "Affects Me" button on that bug.

Comment: Well at least i can stopp questioning my eye-sight. Thanks for this!

Comment: Has something changed in the last year? still looking for it.

Comment: I assume if they had fixed it, then the bug I linked to would be closed, and there would be a comment indicating which version of MySQL Workbench it had been fixed in.

Comment: On the other hand, I upgraded to MySQL Workbench 8.0.22 and it seems it now recognizes CHECK constraints.

Comment: Yes, the last version recognizes them. But as I can see, there is still no way to implement them "automatically" while creating the eer model diagram, it is necessary to add them manually in the code

Comment: Well, as they say, "pull requests welcome." If you want it fixed, write the fix yourself, sign the contributor license agreement, and send them your code.